# Control designer resetting a property to the wrong default value

Tags: c#, winforms

Since most of my container controls use a transparent background color, I created a simple base class for them:

```
public partial class BaseControl : UserControl {
    public BaseControl() {
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Transparent")]
    public override Color BackColor {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }
}
```

My problem is when either inheriting or containing one of them, the designer keeps adding a line in `InitializeComponent()`:

```
control.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
```

When I right-click and choose `Reset` in the properties window, the property is reset to `Transparent`, but when I reopen the window the designer immediately sets it back to `Control`.

Is there another attribute I need to mention for the default to stick?

Comment: FWIW, I looked for similar questions, and the only relevant one I found had code which looked exactly like what I posted here in its answer.

Comment: IIRC, it has something to with `DesignerSerializationAttribute`

Comment: `DesignerSerializationAttribute` can cause the color to never be saved at all - I just don't want it to be reset automatically. My hack for now is to prevent (in the setter) the color from being set if its name is `Control`, which means it will keep the original value, but that means I can never set it to `Control` even if I want to.

Comment: Also, not sure why you removed the `visual-studio-2013` tag - this is an IDE issue, not a language issue.

Comment: It works fine as posted, I have no reasonable theory.  Almost quacks like it is acting transparent at design time as well :)  Best to look at the host control as the troublemaker.

Comment: @HansPassant: This is working with any control I try it. The first time I open the designer when just creating the control, it's set correctly, but whenever I open the designer on a saved file that either inherits or contains this `BaseControl`, then the `BackColor` is set to `Control` again. I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Comment: I already checked that, no repro at all.  Do this the other way around and try to get a repro with what you actually posted in a new project.  Only then you'll have a shot at seeing the difference.

Comment: I've reproduced it with the exact same code as I posted in a bare-bones solution, and uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0QCj6Z5yc40WlZLVXRjWDNydWM/edit?usp=sharing